# yang path expressions to refer to data nodes and schema nodes etc

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-restconf

consider the following yang module

```
module mod {
    yang-version 1;
    namespace "http://example.com/mod";
    prefix m;
    revision "2016-09-09" {
       description "Initial revision.";
    }
    container foo {
        description 'container foo';
        leaf l {
            type string;
        }
    }
}
```

Which path expression is correct in reaching to leaf l ?

```
/mod:foo/l
/m:foo/l
/foo/l
```

If I have 2 revisions of the same module active in my application, how does a client express which revision node he is interested in?

and, is there a path expression available to refer the 'description' of leaf l ?

Comment: You did not specify the context in which you wish to refer to `l`. A leafref path? An XPath expression (must, when)? An XPath expression in a NETCONF get/get-config? A RESTCONF query?

Comment: `I have 2 revisions of the same module active in my application`. A server MUST NOT implement more than one revision of a module, check the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7950#section-5.6.5). Note that in RFC6020, you will not find this explicitly mentioned, but the intention was the same.

Comment: There is no way to directly refer to a description of any node, since there is no need for such a thing. Can you explain your use-case for this in greater detail?

Comment: 1. the path expression I am looking for is the target url in a GET, for ex.  Which of those 3 expressions are correct ?

Comment: my usecase for the 'description' is, something like this. A client submits a yang module to a server. Client wants to make sure that server is seeing the structure correctly. Client says , "show me the description of that leaf", or, "what is the default of a leaf" etc. I guess, it should be just a regular xpath expression w.r.t the yin file. server just needs to handle the expression in whatever way it needs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which path expression is correct in reaching to leaf l ?

In the context of a RESTCONF GET, the scheme described in [draft-ietf-netconf-restconf-16, Section 3.5.3, Encoding Data Resource Identifiers in the Request URI](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-netconf-restconf-16#section-3.5.2) is used.

> A RESTCONF data resource identifier is encoded from left to right,
> starting with the top-level data node, according to the "api-path"
> rule in Section 3.5.3.1.  The node name of each ancestor of the
> target resource node is encoded in order, ending with the node name
> for the target resource.  If a node in the path is defined in another
> module than its parent node, or its parent is the datastore, then the
> module name followed by a colon character (":") MUST be prepended to
> the node name in the resource identifier.  See Section 3.5.3.1 for
> details.

Therefore the correct URI would be something like this:

```
/restconf/data/mod:foo/l
```

> If I have 2 revisions of the same module active in my application, how does a client express which revision node he is interested in?

You cannot express such a request. This is one of the reasons why a server is only allowed to implement a single revision of a YANG module. In YANG 1.1 this is [explicitly](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-5.6.5) prohibited, while in YANG 1.0, this is only implied. Note that respective implemented YANG modules may refer to (import) several revisions of the same module, but only a single one of those may be advertised as implemented (probably the newest one). Since module updating rules are quite strict, definitions will not just go missing in a newer revision of a module, so clients are safe.

> is there a path expression available to refer the 'description' of leaf l ? my usecase for the 'description' is, something like this. A client submits a yang module to a server. Client wants to make sure that server is seeing the structure correctly. Client says , "show me the description of that leaf", or, "what is the default of a leaf" etc.

You seem to be misunderstanding the role of a YANG model. A client does not govern a server's model, it may only govern the data that is described in that model! Such a thing is in the domain of the server and its maintainer.

The only standard way of querying the YANG model (that I am aware of) and not the data modeled by it, would be to obtain the YANG/YIN file from the server (get-schema) and then parse it yourself.

As a side note. A client that implements your module and receives a valid response from a server is inherently aware of which description maps to which XML element/JSON object, because it already did the "mapping" between an instance document and the model (schema) during the validation phase.